# WooCommerce - How to Make Description and Review Boxes Unselectable for Unregistered Users

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to make WooCommerce description and review boxes unselectable for unregistered users. unfortunately there is zero information out there on how to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to add blur css and set "user-select: none", "pointer-events: none".

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#toggleBtn").click(function(){
            $('#btn_id').toggleClass('disabled');
        
            if($('#btn_id').hasClass('disabled')){
                $(this).text('Enable Button');
            }else{
                $(this).text('Disable Button');
            }
      });
    });
```

```css
        .btn{
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            border:1px solid #000;
            border-radius: 4px;
        }
        .disabled{
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
            filter: blur(2px);
            pointer-events: none;
        }
```

```html
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div class="btn">
    <button class="disabled" id="btn_id">Submit</button>
</div>
<button id="toggleBtn">Enable Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple. This can be achieved on CSS or by making core changes to the theme you're using. CSS method is simpler.

If your intention is to make the texts or buttons blurry for unregistered/guest users, you need to add 2 CSS rules.

1. For all users -
   `.woocommerce div.product .woocommerce-tabs .panel { filter: blur(5px); }`
2. For logged in users alone -
   If a user is logged in as an admin or customer, Wordpress adds a class to the body "logged-in" - See pic below. Using that class
   `.logged-in .woocommerce div.product .woocommerce-tabs .panel{ filter: unset; }`

[Logged-in Class in Wordpress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWtxz.png)

**Explanation** -

Adding the first rule will blur elements for all users but the second rule will override the first rule IF a customer is logged in to the website.